# How can I get the Process ID of a specific child process? (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, process, child-process

I would like to get the Process ID of a specific child process (eventually write memory to it). Here is my current code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    DWORD ProcessID;

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "AJ Classic");
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        cout << "Can't find Process." << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcessID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);

        if (ProcessID == NULL) {
            cout << "Can't optain process" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Process ID: " << ProcessID << " | Hex: " << hex << ProcessID << dec << endl;
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Before I move onto the actual memory writing, I want to make sure I get the right process ID.
The process ID I currently get when I run my code is not from the child process I want the proc id of.
This screenshot represents the process I am trying to get the process ID of:

[image]

My code grabs the ID `8120`, but I want it to grab the `14244` process.
How can this be done?

Comment: What distinguishes the process you want from all the other processes with the same name?

Comment: I am confused by that question, Barmar.

Comment: There are a bunch of processes with the same name. You ask for a process with that name, and it returns one of them. But you want a different one. What is the criteria for which one you actually want? What makes 14244 more appropriate than 8120?

Comment: When I use cheat engine on the game, I can only edit values and memory on the process with 14244. I think it has to do with the modules the game uses, so only the second to last child process lets me edit memory

Comment: @Silver that is not likely to be the real reason why 14244 is the only process you can edit.  Also, `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is way too much permissions to ask for just to edit memory. Don't ask for more permissions than you actually need. In this case, you only need to ask for `PROCESS_VM_READ`, `PROCESS_VM_WRITE`, and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`.

Comment: @Silver You need to specify a criteria that can be implemented in the program. How is it supposed to know that `14244` is the right one?

Comment: I guess it's always the second to last child process of the main process

Comment: Then why can I only edit the game values with 14244? How would I be able to edit values in the game with any process ID from the game?

Comment: @Silver what happens when you try to edit the other game instances? Are you getting an error? Please be more specific. As for the order of instances, it is easy to get the start times of all the processes, using [`GetProcessTimes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes). Enumerate the processes, put them in a list/array, and sort them by time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau when I try to edit another process id, nothing happens to the game. 
I can be doing the exact same thing I do on the proper process (14244) but on a different one, and nothing applies. Even when I search for memory, less results show

Comment: @Silver if you are not getting errors, but you are not getting the desired results, then you are most likely simply accessing/modifying the wrong memory. Games tend to use complex structures and memory layouts to optimize performance.

Comment: It seems you need to figure out how the processes are organized and why, so that you can select the correct one. It may not be related to the visible windows at all. The processes in your list are unsorted. If you sort by PID, then the one you want is exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than one top-level window with the given name, you should use
[EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), then in your `EnumWindowsProc` check if that's the window you need; if yes - proceed with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`

Based on comments, this has nothing to do with the window. So, instead of looking for a window `FindWindowA`, you should go through all process using [EnumProcesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes). However, "second from last" is not a good ID; it obviously depends on the sort order. Do you know anything else about HOW to identify your target process?

Comment: OP is asking for a child window,

Comment: @stark - I think he is asking for a child process...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I am just trying to get the process ID of the 2nd to last child process of AJ Classic

Comment: @Silver - please see updated answer

Comment: I don't know anything else on how to identify my target process. And actually it is second from last, for my case it always has been. I have been using the "second to last" process with Cheat Engine for more than 2 years, and it's the only one that works.

Comment: @Silver - well, you can use `EnumProcesses` and see if the order of your `AJ Classic` processes matches your expectations